# OAuth token invalid_grant

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to integrate the Google Plus API into my web application.

I am able to authenticate with Google and I get the code. The problem occurs when I try getting an `access_token` using `HttpClient`.

Here is some code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
        post.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", myCode));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id",
                "my_client_id"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri",
                "http://localhost:8080/test/gplus.do"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret",
                "my_client_secret"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            res = res + output;
        }
```

I have managed to get the token in my mock application several times before, but now it seems to be failing for some unknown reason. All I get is `error:invalid_grant`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure u got the token this way before?
AFAIK, in oAuth, you first call /authorize to get the authorization code, and then, using this code, you make the call to /token to get the access token.

p.s. you can use packages as [Spring for oAuth](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth2), so it makes all the "behind-the-scenes" stuff, all you have to do is to configure the XML.

Comment: Yes, I was getting the token before. What is more, I actually DO get the code, but the problem appears when trying to exchange it for the token. I wouldn't use any library, but if the problem persists, I'll take a look on the one you suggested.

Comment: so the first call (/authorize) is working, but the second fails. 1. What is the error that you see? 2. Try to debug into the HttpClient and see the URL that you try to send to the server. then, use REST-client and try the same URL with it (we try to pinpoint the problem...)

Comment: The problem is that I make the request using httpclient, but somehow I get redirected to my redirect_uri, which makes me make another call for the token. This is when I get the error. Can you tell me how should I proceed?

Comment: simplest thing that comes to my mind - when you are redirected back to your URI, make a check for the token. if it exists - do not make another call to /token. o/w - do ask for the token. HTH...

Comment: Apparently the problem was lying within another part of my code. I was not using some methods as I should have.

Comment: I m getting this as the response 

"Fail{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\n  \"error\" : \"invalid_grant\"\n}","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}",

while calling https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Please help!!!